# How to prove $V*V^T=I$ in SVD?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, svd

How to prove $V*V^T=I$ in SVD: $M=U*S*V^T$?

It's easy to understand $V^T*V=I$. It seems  $V*V^T=I$, but how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $A$ and $B$ are square matrix, such that $AB=I$, then $BA=I$. Because $B$, is inverse of $A$, and the inverse is a matrix is unique.

Comment: So for square matrix, there always exists $AB=I <=> BA=I$, right?

Comment: Yes. And $B$ is inverse of $A$